# Problem using map method to add the value of "checked" to an object

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am using a map method to create a checkmark in a todo app. The function works to add the checkmark but the problem is when I console.log the array and I check on the todo the first todo the value will be checked false. But on the next todo if I check it the value of the first will be true and the second false and so on. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it. And I need these values to be correct so I can use the filter method to clear them

#JS

```
list.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const {
    target
  } = event;
  const parentElement = target.parentNode;
  if (parentElement.className !== 'todo') return;
  const todo = parentElement;
  const todoId = Number(todo.id);

  // target action
  const {
    action
  } = target.dataset;

  action === 'check' && checkTodo(todoId);
});

function checkTodo(todoId) {
  todos = todos.map((todo, index) => ({
    ...todo,
    checked: index === todoId ? !todo.checked : todo.checked,
  }));
  renderTodos();
}

function saveTodo() {
  const todoValue = input.value;
  todos.push({
    value: todoValue,
    checked: false,

    id: Date.now(),
  });
  input.value = '';
  renderTodos();
}
```

Comment: your checkTodo function's logic is correct. What exactly are you trying to achieve ? You are toggling (checked) of the clicked todo ? Provide sample data plox

Comment: it works but it doesn't store the value of 'checked' correctly in the array. and I don't know why. The first todo after i check it the value will be not checked but after i click the second the value will checked for the 1st but for the 2nd and so on

Comment: does your todo have id ? can you do todoId === todo.todoId ? Or index is all you have to target todo ? What about the initial checked state of each todo ?

Comment: Your use of destructuring to get just one property is confusing. Just write `const action = target.dataset.action;`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. The local storage part seems irrelevant, so you can remove it since Stack Snippet doesn't allow it.